# CLR Procedure for Oracle database

Tags: visual-studio-2015, oracle11g, sql-server-2012, clr

Is there any way that we can create `CLR` procedure for `Oracle` in `.Net` application using visual studio 2015 as like there for `SQL Server`.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you download and install [Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2015](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/odacmsidownload-2745497.html) . open vs 2015. new project -> select Oracle project template.
Create your Clr procedure for oracle.

Comment: Thanks @Həsən Cəfərov for your information. i followed the steps you mention in comments and also create project using Oracle Database Project template. But now i am unable to write any c# code here. can you please help me.

Answer (score 0):

See exact solution i want for visual studio 2003

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dotnet/williams-sps-089817.html

But the same solution i am not able to see in VS 2015. can any one have any idea?